# Showing a loading time when loading a page with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I need a help with showing a loading time when user loading a page in a div with ajax with onchange. so this is my code,

So when the page is loading the gif is showing ok but not the time,

```
<div class="col-xs-3" style="display:none;" id="wait"><img src="../img/loading_dark.gif" alt="" style="width: 900px; height: 32px; position: relative;"/>
        <div id="load_time"></div>
</div>
```

and my ajax code,

```
var beforeload = (new Date()).getTime();

        $('#jobname').on('change', $(this), function () {
            var job = $('#jobname').val();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "divpages/show_gen_overview_report.php",
                data: {job: job},
                beforeSend: function ()
                {
                    $("#wait").css("display", "block");
                        var afterload = (new Date()).getTime();
                        seconds = (afterload-beforeload) / 1000;
                    $('#load_time').text('Page load time ::  ' + seconds + ' sec(s).');
                },
                success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    $("#wait").css("display", "none");
                    $('#FinalOverviewReportContentDiv').html(response);
                }
            });
        });
```

what i am trying to do is while the page is loading, the gif is showing alongside the loading time. So, when the page is finished loading user can see how long the page is loading.. thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider following snippet:

```
$('#jobname').on('change', $(this), function () {
    var job = $('#jobname').val();
    var beforeload = new Date();// initialize before sending ajax call not globally
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "divpages/show_gen_overview_report.php",
        data: {job: job},
        beforeSend: function ()
        {
            $("#wait").css("display", "block");
        },
        success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            $("#wait").css("display", "none");
            var afterload = new Date();
            seconds = (afterload-beforeload) / 1000; //calculate in success function not beforesend
            $('#load_time').text('Page load time ::  ' + seconds + ' sec(s).');
            $('#FinalOverviewReportContentDiv').html(response);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is wrong, the `beforesend` variable have to be set in the beforeSend `handler` and `afterload` should be in `success` handler.

You can also use AJAX global events if you wan't it to happen on all AJAX request:

```
var beforeSend = -1;
$.ajaxSend(function() {
  beforeSend = Date.now();

  $("#wait").css("display", "block");
});
$.ajaxComplete(function() {
  var afterSend = Date.now();
  var seconds = (afterSend-beforeSend) / 1000;
  $('#load_time').text('Page load time:  ' + seconds + ' sec(s).');
});
```